# Safety issue exposing sourcemap on live web-application

Tags: javascript, css, debugging, compilation, source-maps

I'm wondering is there is any reason why sourcemap (for SCSS compiling or JS uglifier) should not be available on live environment ?

We are setting this up to help the developers team to debug compiled JS en CSS on our live application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only minifying your script to improve download performance, not to keep your code secret, there shouldn't be any problem with making the source map available.